# Problema al enviar email con archivo al actualizar a PHP 6

Tags: phpmailer

He actualizado a PHP 6 y cuando mando un email funciona correctamente salvo que adjunte un archivo, pues entonces no funciona. Supongo que será el AddAttachment pero no veo el error.
Adjunto el código.

```
require ("../class/class.phpmailer.php");
$contestacion = $_POST['remite']."?subject=Respuesta a ".$_POST['asunto'];
$mensaje = $_POST['correo'];
$mensaje = nl2br($mensaje);
$mimail = $_POST['email'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre']." ".$_POST['cognom'];
$remite = $_POST['remite']; 
$asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
$firma = "WebMaster";
$varname = $_FILES['archivo']['name'];
$vartemp = $_FILES['archivo']['tmp_name'];
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->From = $remite;
$mail->FromName = $firma;
$mail->Subject = $asunto;
$mail->AddAddress($mimail);
if($varname <> " "){
$mail->AddAttachment($vartemp, $varname);
}
$body = "<html>
<body>

</body>
</html>";
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Send();
```

Comment: PHP 6 no existe, existe la 5.6 y de ahí se pasó a la 7 https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Según mi hosting estoy actualizando a PHP 7.3.23, perdón por lo de PHP 6